# Custom Language for Intellij which is extension of HTML

Tags: html, intellij-plugin

I want to create a custom language plugin for intellij for a templating language which is an extension of HTML (it has additional tags). I followed the Custom Language Plugins tutorial on the jetbrains site. But it would require me to have a lexer and parser file. I did not find those files for HTML in the intellij community edition.
Is there maybe an easier way to create a parser by extending the already present HTML parser?

Comment: I myself am just starting plugin development, but what you describe I believe is supported. It might be a good idea to look at existing plugins in the repository and see how they did it.

Comment: Guys, any progress on it? I've come exactly in this situation(but custom syntax inside HTML instead of custom tags). Rainer, if you gain some experience or your project is OSS - please share some info here.

Comment: It should be similar to the angularjs plugin, but I didn't continue with this project, so I can not say anything more specific.